# How to import full json model in three.js

Tags: json, three.js

I'm new to three.js.
We're doing a project and I'm having a trouble in loading JSON model to the index file.

This is what I need.
This is my JSON model code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first Three.js app</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: true });
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 ); // the default
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function (){ 
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
    </script>
</body>
```

And This is my JSON model
        https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybztwwah9ncp68p/scene.json?dl=0
I exported this several times. So I'm pretty sure there's no problem with the JSON model.

But I'm having the problem on loading this JSON model using THREE.ObjectLoader.
It doesn't work. 
This is the code function I used to import the JSON model.

```
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        Loader.load("scene.json",function(obj){
            scene.add(obj);
        });
```

How can this be corrected? I tried many times. 
Any help is appreciated .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'scene.json', function (o) {

        scene.add(o);

    });
```

*see the small "l" at `loader.load`

working example: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_json_claraio.html

if you want to use Object Loader, you must parse your json:
http://threejs.org/docs/api/loaders/ObjectLoader.html

Comment: Thanks. I corrected that mistake. But still it doesn't work.

And I used 
var object = loader.parse( a_json_object );
too. But still it won't work.
Btw, my JSON file is not only an object but a scene. Is it work ?

Can u please help me with the code? It wil be a big help .